# Tensorflow copy of sklearn MLPRegressor produces other results

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am trying to reproduce a deep learning regression result in Tensorflow. If I train a neural network with the MLPRegressor class from sklearn I get very nice results of 98% validation.

The MLPRegressor:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor

I am trying to reproduce the model in Tensorflow. By copying the default values of the MLPRegressor class in a Tensorflow model. However I cannot get the same result. I only get 75% most of the time.

My TF model:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
graph = tf.Graph()
n_input = 3  # n variables
n_hidden_1 = 100
n_hidden_2 = 1
n_output = 1
beta = 0.001

learning_rate = 0.001

with graph.as_default():
    tf_train_feat = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_input))
    tf_train_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None))


    tf_test_feat = tf.constant(test_feat, tf.float32)


    """
    Weights and biases. The weights matix' columns will be the output vector.

    * ndarray([rows, columns])
    * ndarray([in, out])

    tf.placeholder(None) and tf.placeholder([None, 3]) means that the row's size is not set. In the second 
    placeholder the columns are prefixed at 3.
    """
    W = {
        "layer_1": tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
        "layer_2": tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
        "layer_3": tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2, n_output])),
    }


    b = {
        "layer_1": tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_1])),
        "layer_2": tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden_2])),
    }

    def computation(X):
        layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W["layer_1"]) + b["layer_1"])
        layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer_1, W["layer_2"]) + b["layer_2"])
        return layer_2

    tf_prediction = computation(tf_train_feat)
    tf_test_prediction = computation(tf_test_feat)

    tf_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(tf_train_label - tf_prediction, 2)) 
    tf_loss = tf.reduce_mean( tf_loss + beta * tf.nn.l2_loss(W["layer_2"]) )
    tf_optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(tf_loss)
    #tf_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(tf_loss)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

My TF session:

```
def accuracy(y_pred, y):
    a = 0
    for i in range(y.shape[0]):
        a += abs(1 - y_pred[i][0] / y[i])

    return round((1 - a / y.shape[0]) * 100, 3)

def accuracy_tensor(y_pred, y):
    a = 0
    for i in range(y.shape[0]):
        a += abs(1 - y_pred[i][0] / y[i])

    return round((1 - a / y.shape[0]) * 100, 3)

# Shuffles two arrays.
def shuffle_in_unison(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    shuffled_a = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
    shuffled_b = np.empty(b.shape, dtype=b.dtype)
    permutation = np.random.permutation(len(a))
    for old_index, new_index in enumerate(permutation):
        shuffled_a[new_index] = a[old_index]
        shuffled_b[new_index] = b[old_index]
    return shuffled_a, shuffled_b

train_epoch = int(5e4)
batch = int(200)

n_batch = int(X.shape[0] // batch)

prev_acc = 0
stable_count = 0

session = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=graph)
session.run(init)
print("Initialized.\n No. of epochs: %d.\n No. of batches: %d." % (train_epoch, n_batch))

for epoch in range(train_epoch):
    offset = (epoch * n_batch) % (Y.shape[0] - n_batch)


    for i in range(n_batch):
        x = X[offset:(offset + n_batch)]
        y = Y[offset:(offset + n_batch)]

        x, y = shuffle_in_unison(x, y)

        feed_dict = {tf_train_feat: x, tf_train_label: y}
        _, l, pred, pred_label = session.run([tf_optimizer, tf_loss, tf_prediction, tf_train_label], feed_dict=feed_dict)

    if epoch % 1 == 0:
        print("Epoch: %d. Batch' loss: %f" %(epoch, l))
        test_pred = tf_test_prediction.eval(session=session)

        acc_test = accuracy(test_pred, test_label)
        acc_train = accuracy_tensor(pred, pred_label)

        print("Accuracy train set %s%%" % acc_train)
        print("Accuracy test set: %s%%" % acc_test)
```

Am I missing something in the Tensorflow code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very good reason to not use them, regression should have linear output units. I ran into a similar problem a while back and ended up using linear outputs and linear hidden units which seemed to mirror the mlpregressor in my case.

There is a great section in Goodfellow's [Deep Learning Book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org) in [chapter 6](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html), starting at page 181, that goes over the activation functions.

At the very least try this for your output layer

```
 layer_2 = tf.matmul(layer_1, W["layer_2"]) + b["layer_2"]
```

Comment: My layer computations functions returns as you said:


            `layer_2 = tf.matmul(layer_1, W["layer_2"]) + b["layer_2"]`
            `return layer_2`



My accuracy gets a maximum of 78% and then drops, due overfitting I believe, to 72%.

Comment: Maybe add l2 loss to layer1 weights too.

Comment: Also 3 inputs with 100 hidden units seems really high. Lastly try tensor board to visualize the two graphs and check for other differences.

Comment: How do you use tensorboard?

Comment: The book you've mentioned here is 'not' written by MIT. It's by Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio, and Aaron Courville, none of whom are affiliated with MIT. The publisher of the book just happens to be "MIT Press," a very different entity than MIT.